# Type Error executing aapt: Cannot run program "/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.1/aapt": java.io.IOException

Tags: linux, eclipse, android-emulator, aapt

Whenever I try to run android project second time after some changes i get this error. If I close emulator error vanishes. But closing emulator every time is not a feasible solution. What should i do to get rid of this problem?

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error executing aapt: Cannot run program "/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.1/aapt":
java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory: java.io.IOException: error=12, 
Cannot allocate     memory  my_project      line 1  Android ADT Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Hint: On 64-bit systems, make sure the 32-bit libraries are installed: 
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs  my_project      line 1  Android ADT Problem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      check whether ia32-libs installed or not in ubuntu by following command
      dpkg --get-selections ia32-libs
      if you get
      ia32-libs                 install
      then it is installed otherwise you have to install it.
```